# Textbox description in RDLC

Tags: visual-studio, rdlc

I'm creating a `RDLC` report using `Visual Studio 2013` and I'm using a lot of `TextBox` containing formulas.

Is there a way to display some different name for this TextBox instend of just `<<Expression>>` ? This way is not very clear since all the fields seems the same. I see `TextBox` have a `Description` field but it doesn't work for me, it only does if I use `Placeholders`